# How to color ggplot bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having a problem with geom_bar setting the color of the bar edges. I usually use color = "blue" or any other color but now I am getting some lines inside the bars and can't figure out why. See example and screenshot below. Question is, how can I get rid of the lines inside the bars? I tried position = "dodge" but some lines still were showing.

```
data:
b <- structure(list(ForkLength = c(37, 36, 37, 35, 36, 35, 36, 36, 
35, 35, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 36, 38, 36, 37, 37, 38, 38, 36, 35, 
37, 36, 37, 37, 36, 36, 35, 38, 38, 37, 36, 35, 38, 38, 37, 37, 
38, 36, 36, 38, 37, 37, 36, 37, 38, 37, 38, 37, 36, 38, 35, 38, 
37, 39, 38, 37, 38, 38, 39, 39, 36, 38, 35, 37, 36, 39, 37, 39, 
38, 37, 36, 37, 38, 36, 36, 38, 37, 37, 37, 38, 37, 38, 37, 39, 
35, 39, 37, 38, 38, 38, 37, 38, 37, 35, 36, 40), Count = c(1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 
6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(b, aes(x = ForkLength ,y= Count)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', color = "red") +  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: stefan's answer or the duplicate is the real answer you are looking for, but, you could also get away with defining `fill` instead of `color` (more of a workaround).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have multiple observations for each `ForkLenght`. Hence you end up with a stacked bar chart with a lot of small bars. To fix your issue aggregate your data before passing to `ggplot()` or switch to `stat="summary"` with `fun = sum` in `geom_bar` as I do in the code below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(b, aes(x = ForkLength, y = Count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = sum, color = "red") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]